# C#, WinForms: ListBox.Items.Add generates an OutOfMemoryException, why?

Tags: c#, winforms

First off, I found the solution to the exception.  I'm more curious *why* it generated the specific exception it did.

In my scenario I'm adding a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) to a ListBox like so:

```
myListBox.Items.Add(myPOCO);
```

This was generating an `OutOfMemoryException`.  The problem was that `ToString` off the POCO was returning `null`.  I added a `string.IsNullOrEmpty` check to return a "safe" value when null and the exception went away.

Why does this generate an `OutOfMemoryException` and not something else (say a `NullReferenceException`)?

**EDIT**:  Items are added in a for loop.

Full call stack (company-specific references removed) is below.  One thing to note -- the list box is empty when this is called.

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  Message="List box contains too many items."
  Source="System.Windows.Forms"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NativeAdd(Object item)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddInternal(Object item)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add(Object item)
       at <FORM>_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in <PATH>\<FORM>.cs:line 52
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
       at <APP>.Program.Main() in <PATH>\Program.cs:line 25
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Are you adding the items in a loop?

Comment: Under what circumstances would `ToString` return null? Is it when the POCO is extraordinarily large?

Comment: Out of interest, can you post the full stack trace from the exception?

Comment: `ToString` returned null because I was careless...  The POCO is basically just 3 strings.

Comment: @AustinSalonen how did you fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because of the way `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NativeAdd` method is implemented:

```
private int NativeAdd(object item)
{
    int num = (int) base.SendMessage(0x180, 0, base.GetItemText(item));
    switch (num)
    {
        case -2:
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();

        case -1:
            throw new OutOfMemoryException(SR.GetString("ListBoxItemOverflow"));
    }
    return num;
}
```

The [GetItemText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext.aspx) method uses `ToString()` on the object which returns `null` and so a message is sent with `null` parameter, which in turn returns an invalid pointer and you enter the second case which throws the exception.

Comment: Hah, I was going to copy the entire source of the NativeAdd method into my answer, but decided against it... guess I made the wrong choice! :-)

Comment: @Justin -- I was torn but I think this would better help someone else who is getting this problem.

Comment: This happened to me because I had a custom object with a ToString that returned the Name field, and I then stupidly left that field null.

Answer (score 12):

When the underlying [`LB_ADDSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775181(VS.85).aspx) Windows API call fails, WinForms always returns an `OutOfMemoryException`.  A comment in the .NET Framework Reference Source explains why:

```
// On some platforms (e.g. Win98), the ListBox control
// appears to return LB_ERR if there are a large number (>32000)
// of items. It doesn't appear to set error codes appropriately,
// so we'll have to assume that LB_ERR corresponds to item 
// overflow.
// 
throw new OutOfMemoryException(SR.GetString(SR.ListBoxItemOverflow));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get such error then carefully check your code where you are calling `listbox.Items.Add` or `listbox.DataSource = xxxxx`. Whatever `Object` Type is added or bound to list box must return non Null in `ToString()` method. By default .net returns Type name if you do not override `ToString()` method.

If you have implemented your own version of `ToString()` (with override keyword) then make sure method has fail safe to returns non NULL string. See example below how you can add extra 2 lines to avoid such odd error which many people will find totally misleading.

```
//listbox.Items.Add(new MyItem());
//--or--
//listbox.DataSource= new List<MyItem>(){ new MyItem() };

public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Not adding below 2 lines might throw OutOfMemoryException in listbox.Items.Add or listbox.DataSOurce = somelist
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label)) //Added this check to avoid 
            return this.GetType().Name; //Return string.Empty or something other than null else you will get OutOfMemoryException error when you add or bind this object to listbox

        return Label;
    }
}
```